# lighttpd subdomain

Tags: subdomain, lighttpd

Is it possible to configure lighttpd to get this:

subdomain1.127.0.0.1

subdomani2.127.0.0.1
.
.
.

Or something like this:

domainname.com

subdomain.domainame.com

if the domainname is not yet registred, ie. i want it to run on my machine but with all the configuration that will eventualy end up on the real server. I think it would work  with some kind of a reddirect from 127.0.0.1 to domainname.com but only in name but i don't know how to set it up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to test-drive the server locally using the final URLs.  You should be able to do this with your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file).